# How to convert int to string asm win32

Tags: winapi, assembly

So I'm trying to convert a number to a string .

How can i parse a integer value to string using asm win32?

Comment: ... and what have you tried?

Comment: wsprintf,8 not works

Comment: i post this because i don't know how to do it ...

Comment: This is not a homework question is more like for entertainment question.

Comment: You still need to learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) around here.

Comment: Add your wsprintf attempt and the error messages **and** some information about the assembler environment (Masm32, Irvine32, Visual Studio,...).

Comment: [__cdecl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) calling convention ([x64 calling conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx), if you're on 64 bit). With that you can work out how to call [wsprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx).

Comment: Please don't put answers in questions. Add it as an answer. **If** it actually answers the question (yours doesn't). Formatting help is well hidden behind the questionmark in the top right corner. If you are diligent enough, you'll find [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

```
strNumber db 80 dup(0), 0
szFormat db '%ld', 0
dwTheNumber dw 101020

PUSH dwTheNumber
PUSH OFFSET szFormat
PUSH OFFSET strNumber
CALL wsprintfA ; ANSI version
ADD  ESP, 4*3    ; wsprintfA uses the C-calling convention
```

And that's on 32bit

Comment: *szFormat* is an empty string. Consequently, the result will be an empty string.

Comment: @IInspectable Updated.